# Regarding Single Sign On with LDAP and SPNEGO sso

Tags: java

I am using LDAP and SPNEGO for SSO implementation. When my first request goes to LDAP enabled server , in response i am getting TWO www-authenticate header 1)Basic 2)Negotiate. My embeded client pick up only one authentication by String authSchem =  Connection.getHeaderField("WWW-Authenticate"); and that is basic, so how can i use negotiate authentication to get the ticket from SPNEGO . thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check JavaDoc of [#getHeaderField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getHeaderField%28java.lang.String%29) - it returns just a single value:

> If called on a connection that sets the same header multiple times with possibly different values, only the last value is returned.

So this is unusable as with `WWW-Authenticate` you want to walk through the values as they were entered. You need to use [#getHeaderFields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getHeaderFields%28%29) as that will return all headers values.